# Interrupt script from gui button

Tags: scripting, interface

I would like with python blender, a Gui with two buttons one to enter a forever loop, and an other to break the loop.  I'm afraid that when the loop runs the pause button will be unresponsive.

I already searched the forum ; I found that I can kill blender or Ctrl-c the console windows ; but this not what I want. In the first case i lost the data, in the second the python program is just broke (so i can't safely unpause the process.)

To optimize the process the user should be able interact with the scene and release the process again, If it wants to.

What do you think i can do to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe I can run the GUI and the process on two separated threads ?

Comment: Look at the modal operator examples in _`scripts > templates > python`_ For instance in this [related example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/69599/15543) when the button toggle is pressed the modal timer runs till it is toggled.  As to threading, hard to know without knowing what the  other process is doing. [Also possibly related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45731/how-to-run-an-external-command-showing-its-progress-without-locking-blender-e)